# Why does the Data Binding in my Textbox not work?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

my DataBinding in the Textbox does not work. in an different Window i have the same binding on an GridView and this works. They have the same DataContext. After setting TraceLevel to high for debugging I got some warnings. But they don't really help me:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=14200498) for Binding (hash=9369539)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :  Path: 'KundeVM.Skunde.Plz'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=14200498): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.Text (hash=2601186)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=14200498): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=14200498): Found data context element: TextBox (hash=2601186) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=14200498): Activate with root item AppViewModel (hash=35104124)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 107 : BindingExpression (hash=14200498):   At level 0 using cached accessor for AppViewModel.KundeVM: RuntimePropertyInfo(KundeVM)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=14200498): Replace item at level 0 with AppViewModel (hash=35104124), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(KundeVM)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=14200498): GetValue at level 0 from AppViewModel (hash=35104124) using RuntimePropertyInfo(KundeVM): KundeViewModel (hash=39638585)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 107 : BindingExpression (hash=14200498):   At level 1 using cached accessor for KundeViewModel.Skunde: RuntimePropertyInfo(Skunde)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=14200498): Replace item at level 1 with KundeViewModel (hash=39638585), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(Skunde)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=14200498): GetValue at level 1 from KundeViewModel (hash=39638585) using RuntimePropertyInfo(Skunde): <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 106 : BindingExpression (hash=14200498):   Item at level 2 is null - no accessor
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=14200498): TransferValue - got raw value {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 88 : BindingExpression (hash=14200498): TransferValue - using fallback/default value ''
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=14200498): TransferValue - using final value ''
```

Textbox Binding:

```
                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" MaxLength="5" Margin="10 5 " HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding KundeVM.Skunde.Plz,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode = TwoWay, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}">
                </TextBox>
```

DataGrid Binding:

```
            <DataGrid x:Name="MCDaten" ItemsSource="{Binding KundeVM.Kunden}" IsReadOnly="True" SelectedItem="{Binding KundeVM.Skunde, Mode=OneWayToSource}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kundennummer" Binding="{Binding Kunnr, BindsDirectlyToSource=True, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Branche" Binding="{Binding Branche, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Straße" Binding="{Binding Strasse, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="PLZ" Binding="{Binding Plz, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ort" Binding="{Binding Ort, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Skunde property:

```
        private Kunde _skunde;

        public Kunde Skunde
        {
            get { return _skunde; }
            set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _skunde, value); }
        }
```

AppViewModel:

```
    class AppViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private object _currentView;
        public object CurrentView
        {
            get { return _currentView; }
            set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _currentView, value); }
        }

        private KundeViewModel _kundeVM;
        public KundeViewModel KundeVM
        {
            get { return _kundeVM; }
            set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _kundeVM, value); }
        }

        public AppViewModel()
        {
            KundeVM = new KundeViewModel();
            CurrentView = KundeVM;
        }



    }
}
```

Kunde:

```
        private int _id;
        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _id, value); }
        }

        private int _kunnr;
        public int Kunnr
        {
            get { return _kunnr; }
            set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _kunnr, value); }
        }

        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _name, value); }
        }

        private string _branche;
        public string Branche
        {
            get { return _branche; }
            set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _branche, value); }
        }

        private string _strasse;
        public string Strasse
        {
            get { return _strasse; }
            set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _strasse, value); }
        }

        private int _plz;
        public int Plz
        {
            get { return _plz; }
            set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _plz, value); }
        }

        private string _ort;
        public string Ort
        {
            get { return _ort; }
            set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _ort, value); }
        }
```

Im very new and I tried a lot of things but nothing helped.

I have no errors or warnings.

The problem is that it does not work because I have the textbox and the datagrid in seperate windows.
Both windows have the same DataContext.
If i have it in the same window everything works fine but this is not what I need.

The structure [Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeQ84.png)

Thanks for help

Comment: Something seems to be null. First thing I would try is: <textbox> with binding to KundeVM and a second textbox binding to KundeVM.Kunden. Maybe with a fallback value each. Do they both display an object?

Comment: I cant bind to KundeVM.Kunden because Kunden is a ObservableCollection. And no they dont display anything.

Comment: It should at least display that there's a collection. What is also strange: Why do you have to specify "KundeVM". The VM sould be the default (DataContext) for Bindungs. Or is it a sub VM?

Comment: I edited my Question. My DataContext is set to the AppViewModel

Comment: It can be, that `Skunde` is `null`. There is not enough code to see the issue (What is `KundeVM`? How `Skunde` being set? Where `KundeVM.Kunden` being filled?). So please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially about _How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_.

Comment: You can type something in the textbox and Skunde would not be null. Also you can see that the SelectedItem in the Gris is Skunde so it can't be 0. I have an Message box and it displays me Skunde.Plz when i select an item in the grid. This works. But the textbox does not get any data. KundeVM.Kunden is an observableCollection that gets his data from an database but this does not matter because that works fine. I only have problems with Skunde and textbox binding.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made a sample source, and it works well.
Would you try this? Full source is in **[Github](https://github.com/devncore/community/tree/main/stackoverflow/answers/textbox-databinding-sample)**.

#### Structure

[image]

#### AppViewModel

```cs
public class AppViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private object _currentView;
    public object CurrentView
    {
        get { return _currentView; }
        set { _currentView = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private KundeViewModel _kundeVM;
    public KundeViewModel KundeVM
    {
        get { return _kundeVM; }
        set { _kundeVM = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public AppViewModel()
    {
        KundeVM = new KundeViewModel();
        CurrentView = KundeVM;
    }
}
```

#### KundeViewModel

I filled `Kunden` when `KundeViewModel` was loaded.

```cs
public class KundeViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private Kunde _skunde;
    public Kunde Skunde
    {
        get { return _skunde; }
        set { _skunde = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Kunde> _kunden;
    public ObservableCollection<Kunde> Kunden
    {
        get { return _kunden; }
        set { _kunden = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public KundeViewModel()
    {
        Kunden = GetKunden();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Kunde> GetKunden()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Kunde> source = new ObservableCollection<Kunde>
        {
            new Kunde { Plz = 0 },
            new Kunde { Plz = 1 },
            new Kunde { Plz = 2 },
            new Kunde { Plz = 3 },
            new Kunde { Plz = 4 }
        };
        return source;
    }
}
```

#### AppView.xaml

```xml
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <DataGrid x:Name="MCDaten"
              ItemsSource="{Binding KundeVM.Kunden}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding KundeVM.Skunde, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
              IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="30" Grid.Column="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="PLZ" Binding="{Binding Plz, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" MaxLength="5" Width="300" Height="30"
             Text="{Binding KundeVM.Skunde.Plz, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Grid>
```

#### AppView.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class AppView : UserControl
{
    public AppView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new AppViewModel();
    }
}
```

#### Result

- **When select the grid item**

[image]

- **When change the value of `TextBox`**

[image]

Comment: I have the textboxes and the grid in seperate windows

Comment: I want to have something like a "matchcode". This is why I need it in an seperate Window. When I have the textboxes in the same window as the Gridview everythings works fine. But if I have it in another window it does not work. Both windows have the same Datacontext

Comment: I misunderstood and updated the code that `Datagrid` and `TextBox` seperate into different windows, so please try again. [Github](https://github.com/devncore/stackoverflow-sample/tree/main/src/answers/textbox-databinding-sample)

Comment: Thanks your sample helped me to find an solution

Answer (score -1):

From what I remember and have encountered, is that you can NOT do a 3-part binding reference such as your textbox set to "KundeVM.Skunde.Plz"  (viewModel.secondaryObject.someProperty).  To resolve, you should update the "DataContext", either at the form's level, or at the inner control.

If all your controls are always somehow bound to the "KundeVM" object, then at your form/window level, set its

```
DataContext = {Binding KundeVM}
```

Then, everywhere else in your form/window you do not need that additional context of KundeVM.  Everything from that level down will default to ...oh, that is where my stuff is...   Doing that way, your text binding would be dropped down to just "Skunde.Plz".

Now, if you have multiple objects/properties at your KundeVM level, you could still work by adjusting your textbox by declaring ITS data context to the KundeVM and then the text would be the specific underlying source.  This way, you don't mess up whatever the rest of your form/window bindings are. (stripping out other non-important stuff)

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding KundeVM.Skunde.Plz}" />
```

would become

```
 <TextBox DataContext={Binding KundeVM} Text="{Binding Skunde.Plz}" />
```

But if you did at the window level

```
<Window x:Class="YourAppNamespace.YourClass" 
    DataContext="{Binding KundeVM}" 
    ... rest of window stuff ... >


    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Kunden}" IsReadOnly="True" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding Skunde, Mode=OneWayToSource}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <.. rest of data grid content .. >
    </DataGrid
           
     <TextBox Text="{Binding Skunde.Plz}" />

</Window>
```

Notice the second example, at the window level data context you START with KundeVM, so everything else within the window is a child property/object from that point.  Does this help resolve your issue?

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I tried it but it still does not work.

Comment: @sh272727, next thing I would try.  Comment out your failing "Plz" column.  Also show the structure of your "Kunde" class.  Is there something missing about that one particular field?  Please edit your original post with additional information.  Keep removing columns until the data does allow for presentation, then gradually add back until failure again.  I too have had similar and could just be that the textbox "Plz" is not defaulted with an empty string value and is null?

Comment: It is not failing. The xaml recognizes the Plz as int and the other fields as their datatypes. But the binding does not work. If I write something in the textbox the value in Plz does not change. If I select something in the Grid, the Plz does change the value but the textbox does not load the plz.